# How do I use a toggle button to change HTML views using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a toggle button to act as something similar to the DARK/LIGHT mode function. However, in my case, I want it to change the HTML view without refreshing the page.

```
<div class='container'>
<h1 class='headertekst'>".$outlet." - ".$monthName." ".$choosen_date_year." Theoritical: </h1>
<label class='switch' for='view'>
<input type='checkbox' name='view' id='view' checked onclick='view()' >
<span class='slider round'>
</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Once onclick I want it to echo different HTML codes

```
function view() {
if (document.getElementById('view').checked) 
{
  //echo my HTML codes
} else {
 //echo another set of HTML codes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but try it with the `document.boy.innerHTML` property to change the body html. Notify me if you meant something else

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of html body like this:

```
function view() {
if (document.getElementById('view').checked) 
{
 document.body.style.backgroundColor =  'black';
} else {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor =  'white';
  }
}
```

Comment: a better way to do is to create a dark classe and toggle it from the javascript?
`document.body.classList.toggle('dark');`